# Why UIButton doesn’t appear on the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I create `UIButton` but it doesn’t appear on the screen.

**In .h File :**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton * button;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage * Image1;
```

**In .m File :**

```
_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_button addTarget:self action:@selector(_button1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 437, 765);

_Image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
[_button setBackgroundImage:_Image1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview: _button];
```

Why this button doesn’t work?

But this button work.

```
UIButton *button1;
button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 437, 765);

UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
[button1 setBackgroundImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:button1];
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `doesn't work` ?

Comment: button does not appear on the screen

Comment: How you define `_button`, property or ivar ?

Comment: Change it from weak to strong. Why do you have an IBOutlet if you're creating the button in code?

Comment: @JamesP These are two different variants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your properties this way:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton * button;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage * Image1;
```

Strong means your button and image will be retained, at the moment they are deallocated before you get a chance to add them to the screen.

IBOutlets can be weak as they are already retained by the view, however you're creating your button programmatically, not using interface builder.